# How can i add drop downs to a page with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an order form for ordering shirts. I want to have a drop down to let the user select how many they want to purchase, depending on what they choose i want to add or remove drop downs for the size of each shirt.

There is one size drop down on the page initially along with the quantity drop down. If they select 3 from the quantity drop down, I want two more size drop downs to show up populated with the available sizes, small through XXL, for the user to select the sizes they want for the extra shirts.

How can I do this?

This is the size drop down i need to add when they select a quantity. And the drop down for quantity with 1 through 10.

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <p><img src="shirt.png" width="200" height="201" /></p>
        <p>Size:
            <label>
                <select name="shirtsize" id="shirtsize" id="size">
                    <option>please choose</option>
                    <option>Small</option>
                    <option>Medium</option>
                    <option>Large</option>
                    <option>XL</option>
                    <option>XXL </option>
                </select>
            </label>
            <br />
            Price: $15.00
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What does your html look like? (The actual html, not a *description of* your html).

Comment: That's going to get pretty hairy. Let's say they want 10 shirts. You then have 10 select boxes for each of the sizes. You would have to grab each of those on the other side of the submit. Is it not plausible to just force them to add x amount of one size to the cart at a time?

Comment: Actually, that's not a bad idea. Just have text boxes for quantity of each size. I overcomplicated the hell out of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JQuery:

```
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i=1;i<10;i++){
        $('#num').append('<option value="' + i + '">'+ i +'</option>');
    }
    var str = "<select><option>S</option><option>M</option><option>L</option></select>";
    $('#num').change(function (){
        var num = $('#num option:selected').val();
        $('#sizes').empty();
        for (var i =1; i<=num ; i++){
            $('#sizes').append($(str));
        }
    });
});
</script>
<body>
<div>select amount:<select id="num"></select></div>
<div>select size:<div id="sizes"></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```